# ASP.NET Core Web API and Entity Framework simultaneously check if entity exists in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Web API project using Entity Framework.
API requests are constantly coming from a source and I receive them, I check with linq whether the account number field has been added to the database before, if not, I add it, but sometimes 20 requests can come from the API source at the same time and duplicate records may occur.

How can I prevent this situation?

```
var account = dbContext.Accounts
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountNumber == apiMessage.AccountNumber);

if (account is null)
{
    account = new Account();
    account.AccountNumber = apiMessage.AccountNumber;
}
```

Comment: Best would be to create a **unique constraint** on that column in the database table - so no matter how many simultaneous requests you get and try to store, the database will reject any inserts that try to use an account number that's already been used....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to solve the problem at database level. Also property can be null so I don't want to use unique constraint.
I'm trying to solve the problem in API layer.

Comment: "I don't want to solve the problem at database level" - but it's a database level problem. if there are _valid_ null values, then you should run an UPSERT on the ... sorry ... db level. in order to solve this (correctly) at the api level you would end up duplicating functionality that already exists in .... you guessed it, the db. why do you want to solve it at the api level?

Comment: I would agree with @ShaiCohen but if you were to solve it in code, it sounds like you would need to add some kind of queue so you can process the responses FIFO.

Comment: @ShaiCohen yes it'a database level problem but my problem is about threads.
If I can solve it with approaches like ConcurrentQueue or Channel I don't need to fix the database.

Comment: I think [caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0) may help you.

Comment: maybe go with que route.like MSMQ or something like this

Answer (score 1):

Just handle it in database side to make it easy. Add Unique constraint in the AccountNumber column.

You can handle the migration in your EF configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Account>()
        .HasIndex(u => u.AccountNumber)
        .IsUnique();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to solve the problem at database level. Also property can be null so I don't want to use unique constraint. I'm trying to solve the problem in API layer.

Comment: Try passing the save action in a Thread Pool. Queueing is another approach.  Service Bus, MSMQ or ConcurrentQueue

http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-concurrentqueue

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the controller to finish before starting a new one (No concurrent calls), but that will not be a good solution.

If you do that, the requests will either wait for their turn, which decreases performance.

Or they will not run at all if the controller is already working, which will result in a controller not answering all the requests.

Comment: I know this do you have any idea about ConcurrentQueue or Channel with EntityFramework ?

Comment: _wait for the controller to finish_ - what do you mean? Each request creates new controller instance.

Comment: So, make each controller check config.json for a value that specifies if any instance of that controller is running. Then if there is none change the value and start the process, once the process is finished change the value back. This way only 1 instance can make changes to the db. That sort of solution was what I was implying.